# how to display items from a get intent in textviews

Tags: java, android, kotlin

What I need to do is take items from a get intent and place them in textviews. the problem is I have no clue how?

my code

```
class DisplayActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.display_activity)

    val Atext1 = intent?.getStringExtra(customview.Atext)

    val Btext2 = intent?.getStringExtra(customview.Btext)

    val Ctext3 = intent?.getStringExtra(customview.Ctext)

    println("findit,$Atext1,$Btext2,$Ctext3")

}
```

I know the parse this way because the show up In the console But how do I take my vals and place them in text views.

the closest I've gotten is this

```
class DisplayActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
var Atext1 = intent?.getStringExtra(customview.Atext)

var Btext2 = intent?.getStringExtra(customview.Btext)

var Ctext3 = intent?.getStringExtra(customview.Ctext)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.display_activity)


    println("findit,$Atext1,$Btext2,$Ctext3")

    Atext1 = findViewById<View>(R.id.text_1).toString()

    Btext2 = findViewById<View>(R.id.text_2).toString()

    Ctext3 = findViewById<View>(R.id.text_3).toString()

}
```

But the problem with this is that everything comes up null

here's the customview class from my adapter

```
class customview(val view: View,var thing :Mlist? = null): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

companion object{
    val Atext = "text1"
    val Btext = "text2"
    val Ctext = "text3"

}
init {
    view.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(view.context, DisplayActivity::class.java)

        intent.putExtra(Atext, thing?.text1)
        intent.putExtra(Btext, thing?.text2)
        intent.putExtra(Ctext, thing?.text3)

        view.context.startActivity(intent)

    }
}
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here any help would be much appreciated

if you need to see the adapter or the XML for display_activity to help me please feel free to say so and I will post. I just don't want this to be super long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is coming form this line:

> Atext1 = findViewById(R.id.text_1).toString()

You are modifying the value of Atext1, but what you want is to set R.id.text_1 text property to Atext1.

Also I guess that R.id.text_1 is a TextView (not a View).

Please try

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_1).text=Atext1
```

Comment: this does not work. I says unresolved reference: text. thanks though

Comment: I edited the answer, R.Id;text_1 is probably a TextView, original code sees it as a View